# Best practice using css positioning element

Tags: css

so I'm just starting my career as a **web designer**, working on my first project now, i just finished the first page design, but anyway i have some worries about the css design that I created, mainly about **positioning the html elements**. here's the code samples:

```
.contentbackground
{
   background-image: url('../images/body/BG.png');
   width: 1218px;
   height: 370px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 205px;
   margin-left: 67px;
}
.loginbox
{
   width: 351px;
   height: 280px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 40px;
   right: -12px;
}
.lblLogin
{
   position: absolute;
   top: 85px;
   right: 265px;
   font-family: "Century Gothic";
   font-size: 16px;
   color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

the question is, is this approach the best practice? i mean, set the position absolute, and manually configure the top, left, right, bottom placement, is it recommended?

Comment: Can you show us the result?

Comment: you mean the image result?

Comment: I would not recommend doing that for all elements, as it will be a pain to render it across screen sizes. Use relatively placed elements and only use an absolute position where needed (ie. overlapping elements)

Comment: @AbieGiordano, AldiUnanto means (I think) a working example like jsfiddle, with html code.

Comment: It depends on what are you trying to do. But in general, I would say it's a bad practice

Comment: @Oriol so what's the recommended solution? should i use relative positioning on all the css? can you explain? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you don't have to put `position: absolute` for every element, it's not good. You can use `absolute` for only particular case. The fact is, `position: absolute` will put an element everywhere and it's may out of flow, and it **won’t affect or be affected** by any other element in the flow. You can learn more about **positioning** here :

1. Course -> http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-6merh
2. Learn and sample -> http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101

Answer (score 0):

Using `position: absolute` depends on your html code and the parents of your element. But generally using 3 absolute position in a same time is not recommended!
you can use both `relative` and `absolute` for more effective way for positioning.
to understand position in CSS I suggest to watch below movie:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jx5jmI0UlXU